# See local windows shares from linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, networking

I was wondering if it is possible to see all the local windows shares on linux. Under windows I used to be able to see the public files of everyone "near me", is there anyway to replicate this under ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to use Samba though.

Her'es a tutorial on how to connect to windows shares.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/access-windows-shares-from-linux/ from command line.

Here's the Samba documentation which shows how to view shares near you in Ubuntu depending on your windowing system. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba